# PHPMailer Encoding 8 bit

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a weird problem with the Content-Transfer-Encoding of the emails I sent.

In add the following line:

```
$mail->Encoding = '8bit';
```

In my code, but the emails sent with quoted-printable...

In the source:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I don't know how to do for sending my emails with a Content-Transfer-Encoding in 8bit...

`$mail->Encoding = '8bit';` seems to doesn't work...

All the code:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->setLanguage('fr', './PHPMailer/language/');

$mail->CharSet    = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding   = '8bit';
$mail->Host       = 'my_domain.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'news@my_domain.com';
$mail->Password   = 'my_password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->From       = 'news@my_domain.com';
$mail->FromName   = 'bla';
$mail->addAddress('my@mail.net');
$mail->addReplyTo('news@my_domain.com', 'bla');
$mail->AddCustomHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n");
$mail->WordWrap   = 10000;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject    = 'Subject';
$mail->Body       = 'bla';
$mail->AltBody    = "bla";

$mail->send();
```

Big thanks for help

Comment: Can you please add full email code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I wrote that code. [RFC5322 section 2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.1.1) imposes a hard line length limit in email messages (it's a MUST requirement in the spec). If you've specified an encoding that does not allow variation in line length without altering the content (such as `8bit`), PHPMailer automatically switches to `quoted-printable` encoding. This approach means that your exact content is preserved through the encoding, while allowing long lines to be wrapped.

If you want to avoid this, wrap (or otherwise reduce) your line lengths so they are less than 998 chars.

Just because you will often be able to get away with this, you shouldn't, if only on the basis of [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Comment: can $mail->WordWrap do the job ?

Comment: Indeed, with a really small content, Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit ! But with a true big html content, how can I do ?.. :(

Comment: You can give `WordWrap` a try, but you may find edge cases where the added line breaks prevent HTML from working properly, or cause client browser compatibility issues, so you're probably better off imposing your own policy, or just simplifying your content. If your HTML is bigger than about 30k you should consider simplifying it anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks Synchro, I will establish a line splitter.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's intentional. You're possibly hitting this line of code inside `\PHPMailer::createBody()`:

```
//If lines are too long, and we're not already using an encoding that will shorten them,
//change to quoted-printable transfer encoding
if ('base64' != $this->Encoding and self::hasLineLongerThanMax($this->Body)) {
    $this->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
    $bodyEncoding = 'quoted-printable';
}
```

... where the line length limit is hard-coded to 1000:

```
/**
 * Detect if a string contains a line longer than the maximum line length allowed.
 * @param string $str
 * @return boolean
 * @static
 */
public static function hasLineLongerThanMax($str)
{
    //+2 to include CRLF line break for a 1000 total
    return (boolean)preg_match('/^(.{'.(self::MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 2).',})/m', $str);
}
```

I can't tell you for sure but it's possible that mail specs simply do not allow long lines (even though in practice they often *seem* to work).